# Specifying documents directory as file output URL while working with Glimpse in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, glimpse

I'm using [Glimpse](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse) to record the contents of a UIView so it can save it to a file in the documents directory. I'm having trouble specifying a URL for the file output in the g.startRecording line in viewDidLoad. I'd like to have the return value from `getDocumentsDirectory()` set as the URL but placing the method name as the parameter does not work. I have also tried to use `documentsDirectory` and this does not work either and results in "Ambiguous use of 'startRecording" I am using Swift here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    var player: VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
    let g: Glimpse = Glimpse()

    let url = URL(string: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let media = VLCMedia(url: url!)
        player.media = media
        player.delegate = self
        player.drawable = videoView


        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]


        player.play()
        g.startRecording(videoView) { (documentsDirectory) in
            <#code#>
        }

    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        player.stop()
        recorder.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the error. It seems "getDocumentsDirectory" method no where used in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `urls[0]` when you should just use `.url` instead.  Example:

```
func write(_ data: Data, to filename: String) throws {
    let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
    let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)
    try data.write(to: fileURL)
}
```