# Capturing RTSP stream from UIView using MobileVLCKit

Tags: ios, swift, rtsp, libvlc

I'm using MobileVLCKit to stream using RTSP and need to save the live stream for later playback. I've tried using Glimpse to capture the contents of the UIView my VLCPlayer is in however I am still stuck specifying the output URL ([Specifying documents directory as file output URL while working with Glimpse in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570539/specifying-documents-directory-as-file-output-url-while-working-with-glimpse-in))

Is there possibly a way to do this with MobileVLCKit? Previously I have tried to use FFmpeg but the quality of the stream was not good and VLC provided better performance. I just need to be able to stream RTSP, and capture it. Does anyone know how of a way that I can do this? If MobileVLCKit cannot do this I am open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

version 3.2.0 added recording APIs

```
new recording Api
VLCMediaPlayerDelegate:
    - (void)mediaPlayerStartedRecording:(VLCMediaPlayer *)player;
    - (void)mediaPlayer:(VLCMediaPlayer *)player recordingStoppedAtPath:(NSString *)path;
VLCMediaPlayer:
    - (BOOL)startRecordingAtPath:(NSString *)path;
 - (BOOL)stopRecording;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add options into media and call startRecording again

`player.media.addOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264}:std{access=file,dst=" + [Your Path File] + "}")`